# I have a Nest 3rd generation thermostat and it wont turn on the furnace

Tags: hvac, nest

I have a Nest 3rd generation thermostat and it wont automatically turn on my furnace i have to the nest to off then turn back to On to get the furnace to start. It was running fine for about 2 months and now its just acting up. i tried resetting it to erase my learned part but it did nothing. I have a gas furnace and central air attached to the unit.

Comment: When you installed it, did you connect the C wire?

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?